# Qt drawing icons using color and alpha-map

Tags: qt, icons, alpha, qpainter

I would like to draw icons (only one color) in different colors. To do so, I would like to import a single alpha-texture and then combine this with a given color in the application.

The result should be, that nothing is drawn on to the background, when the alpha-map has an opacity of 0 and the used color should be drawn, when the opacity is 1.

One soulution should be hidden somewhere in `QPainter`, since you can manually set the Composition-Mode (`QPainter::setCompositionMode`). But I don't get it to work like I want.

Does somebody have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is a little graphic explaining what I would like to do. I want to use a Alpha-Map like shown in the graphic and then use a color layer to create my icon. Important is, that the background stays transparent.

[image]

Comment: "I don't get it to work like I want." If you claim that you have code that doesn't work, you should post the code - in fact, you should post a self contained example that lets us compile it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do thos using QPainter like this:

```
QColor color;
// set color value

// load gray-scale image (an alpha map)
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap(":/images/earth.png");

// initialize painter to draw on a pixmap and set composition mode
QPainter painter(&pixmap);
painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn);

painter.setBrush(color);
painter.setPen(color);

painter.drawRect(pixmap.rect());

// Here is our new colored icon!
QIcon icon = QIcon(pixmap);
```

Here is gray-scale image and two colored icons which i get using the code above (QPixmap.save() method):
[icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqpWm.png)

Comment: For some reason I had to replace the set brush, pen and drawRect lines with `painter.fillRect(pixmap.rect(), color)`  (in python). Less code and works, so that is nice. I also have `painter.end()` but not sure if that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The `DestinationIn` composition mode will do the trick.

1. Draw the color layer using the default composition mode of `SourceOver`.
2. Draw the alpha layer using the `DestinationIn` composition mode.

For example:

[image: screenshot]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/alpha-mask-24943711
#include <QtWidgets>

QImage icon(int size) {
   QImage image{size, size, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied};
   image.fill(Qt::transparent);
   QPainter p(&image);
   p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
   p.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
   p.translate(image.rect().center());
   p.scale(image.width()/2.2, image.height()/2.2);
   p.setBrush(Qt::white);
   p.drawEllipse(QRectF{-.5, -.5, 1., 1.});
   p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn);
   p.setBrush(Qt::transparent);
   p.drawEllipse(QRectF{-.3, -.3, .6, .6});
   for (auto angle : {0., 100., 150.}) {
      p.save();
      p.rotate(angle);
      p.drawRect(QRectF{-.1, 0, .2, -1.});
      p.restore();
   }
   return image;
}

QImage checkers(int size) {
   QImage img{size*2, size*2, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied};
   QPainter p(&img);
   p.fillRect(0, 0, size, size, Qt::darkGray);
   p.fillRect(size, size, size, 2*size, Qt::darkGray);
   p.fillRect(size, 0, size, size, Qt::lightGray);
   p.fillRect(0, size, size, size, Qt::lightGray);
   return img;
}

void drawColorIcon(QPainter & p, QColor color, const QImage & alpha)
{
  p.save();
  p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver);
  p.fillRect(QRect{0, 0, alpha.width(), alpha.height()}, color);
  p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn);
  p.drawImage(0, 0, alpha);
  p.restore();
}

QImage drawColorIconProof(QColor color, const QImage & alpha) {
   QImage result{alpha.size(), alpha.format()};
   QPainter p(&result);
   drawColorIcon(p, color, alpha);
   p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationAtop);
   p.fillRect(alpha.rect(), {checkers(10)});
   return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QLabel label;
   label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(drawColorIconProof("orangered", icon(200))));
   label.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. However, instead of using a transparent graphic for the alpha map like I've used in the first post, I had to use a black/white-graphic where black pixels are transparent and white pixels are not (=rendered).

```cpp
// ++++ in constructor ++++ 
QImage alphaMap = QImage(fileName);

QColor color;

// ++++ in paint Event ++++

QPainter painter(this);
painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::RenderHint::Antialiasing);
painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::RenderHint::HighQualityAntialiasing);

// draw icon
QImage renderedIcon(alphaMap);  
// fill with color
renderedIcon.fill(color);                   
// set alpha-map, black pixels -> opacity of 0, white pixels -> opacity 1
renderedIcon.setAlphaChannel(alphaMap);     

painter.drawImage(this->rect(), renderedIcon);  // draw image to QWidget
```

Comment: Since `QWidget::rect()` always starts at 0,0, you can simply have `painter.drawImage(0, 0, renderedIcon)`. You also don't necessarily need a custom widget for this - you could pass a `QPixmap::fromQImage` to a label. Of course if you need to render many such icons, it certainly saves memory to have a custom widget do the job.

Comment: Hi,
I also do some other stuff with the Icon like changing the color when hovering etc. Thats why I think a custom widget is usefule here. ;) 

Thanks for the hint with `rect()`. I didn't realy looked into the documentation and thought it also determins the size. ;D

Answer (score -1):

I do not quite understand the problem, but may be you can use QGraphicsColorizeEffect class? [QGraphicsColorizeEffect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicscolorizeeffect.html)

Comment: Hi, 

I already thought that I didn't made a good job in explaining my problem. I will add a graphic which should help understanding me. :)

I will try the QGraphicsColorizeEffect.